# What does this achieve?

Tags: shell-script

What's the point of this:

```
abort() {
  { if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then cat -
    else echo "rbenv: $*"
    fi
  } >&2
  exit 1
}
```

[source](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/blob/master/libexec/rbenv)

Answer (score 3):

If there are zero arguments provided to the function (`"$#" -eq 0`), then read from a preceeding pipe (`cat -`) instead, and redirect any output from this block to srderr (`>&2`).

This allows them to things like `abort "shell integration not enabled...` or

```bsh
  { rbenv---version
    rbenv-help
  } | abort
```

and if any errors are encountered in doing so (e.g. the pipe provided no output and there were no arguments), those will also be surfaced to the user.